# Get the roster of a contact (e.g. friends of a friend or friends of a contact in MUC) in xmpp

Tags: javascript, xmpp, openfire

Is it possible to get the roster of a contact (i.e. the roster of my roster contact or the roster of an occupant in a MUC)?

Comment: No.  That would be a huge breach of privacy if enabled by default.  You most likely have to write a server plugin, which would be able to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can induce your friend to *send* you their roster, you can use [XEP-0144](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0144.html), "Roster Item Exchange" as the protocol:

```
<message from='horatio@denmark.lit' to='hamlet@denmark.lit'>
  <body>Some visitors, m'lord!</body>
  <x xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/rosterx'> 
    <item action='add'
          jid='rosencrantz@denmark.lit'
          name='Rosencrantz'>
      <group>Visitors</group>
    </item>
    <item action='add'
          jid='guildenstern@denmark.lit'
          name='Guildenstern'>
      <group>Visitors</group>
    </item>
  </x>
</message>
```